# Hibernate. 2 functions : simpleSave() , saveWithCascade() . can it be done ? and how?

Tags: java, hibernate, cascade

I have a scenario in which i have:
A parent class Parent which has some simple properties (int, String, etc) and 2 set of children. 
Set childrenA;
Set childrenB;

Could i make a save function for parent simpleSave(Parent p) that will save/persists only the parent properties in the database and have a function saveWithCascade(Parent p) that will cascade to its children ?

**later edit: by Save i actually mean Update. Because if i know that only a property or a set changed, i dont want hibernate to do lots of selects on the others just to check if they changed**

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Assuming that you have your hibernate mappings defined appropriately. You can call `session.save(Parent)`

When you are saving a child, you can do some thing like this in your method

```
Parent p = new Parent();
Child c = new Child();
p.addChild(c);
session.save(p);
session.flush();
session.save(c);
session.flush();
```

Important thing is to ensure that the child drives the relationship. You can do that by setting `inverse = "true"`

Comment: What if its just a one way relationship from parent to child ?

Comment: You don't have to do anything. By default inverse = "false"

Answer (score 0):

If you configure Hibernate to cascade a particular operation for a given association, you can't disable it. So the only want to achieve what you want would be to not cascade PERSIST and MERGE and to do everything manually in your `saveWithCascade()` method.